# C# compare datetime with current datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if my application datetime (e.g. 10/18/2012 4:09:41 PM) was created 30 hours ago?

Comment: what do you mean by application date time?

Comment: sorry, its just a field in my application.

Comment: What have you tried? I would parse the string into a DateTime then compare it to a TimeSpan.  This question indicates you have done zero research on how to do this.

Comment: thank you all for your help, sorry didn't think my not working code would be useful, curios, so the reason I didn't provide my not working code I got -9? want to know for my future reference. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just substract two dates

```
TimeSpan diff = date2.Subtract(date1);
       if(diff.Hours > 30)
{
//do action;
}
```

Comment: You should explain how to use a TimeSpan if your going to provide code. The author clearly doesn't understand how to.

Answer (score 2):

Difference of 2 dates returns TimeSpan. TimeSpan has properties for hours, minutes and seconds. You may use:

```
int hours = (date2-date1).Hours;
```

It returns hours. You may use the variable hours in any condition.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.AddHours(-30) == "application datetime" (your variable name)

Comment: This makes no sense.  This code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Oh really? "application datetime" - is date time variable name

Comment: @Ramhound please explain your comment.

Comment: @rs The code attempts to compare a DateTime to a string. It won't compile.

Comment: "application datetime" as author (Ben) said is a name of DateTime field in his application, so in fact it is something like 
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-30) == DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract the `DateTime`s to get a `TimeSpan`, and then look at the `.Days` property:

```
var span = secondDate.Subtract(firstDate);
var days = span.Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime appDate = new DateTime(2012, 10, 18, 16, 9, 41);
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(appDate);
if(diff.Hours > 30)
{
    // Application older than 30 hours
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime('10/18/2012 4:09:41 PM');
double hrs = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d2).TotalHours;
```