# Update ListviewItems where value is a DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, listviewitem

I have a `Listview` with the columns `Dealer`, `RecievedDate`, `ResolvedDate`, `Aging` and `Status` (`active` and `closed`).

I need to update all the rows whose `Status` is `active`, where the `Aging` is the difference of the current date and the `RecievedDate` every load of the form.

Comment: I think you may need a `Timer`

Comment: A `Timer` will do nothing for you, disregard that.  What part are you struggling with?  [Comparing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979912/3773066) `DateTimes`? *How* to do the update?  *When* to do the update (see above by @waltmagic)? Something else?

Comment: I want all the recievedDates (with the status active) to be subtracted to the Current time.. i will do the update after loading my form..